# WCF DS client return less results than the same request in the browser

Tags: wcf-data-services

Strange thing:

```
var data = GetDataClient(); // trivial code
var query = data.UserTrackers.Expand("TodayNews");
Console.WriteLine(query);
var trackers = query.ToArray(); 
// only 3 results despite the fact that Fiddler shows the resonse with 10 instances.
```

Comment: Are trackers unique with unique primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is this is because the user tracker instance is already in the client before you queried, and the default MergeOption is AppendOnly.

Can you try changing the MergeOption to OverwriteChanges and see what happens?

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: This code is from unittest and therefore there can not be any other instance because the only request is sent to the server.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the clr class definition and the payload coming from the server (maybe a fiddler trace or something). I am assuming that you are using .net framework 4.0 client assemblies in your project.